# Codeigniter 3 model function no return variable

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter

I'm making a project where a user can publish/post their own stories and read others' stories. Very simple.

This is my controller method named publish:

```
  public function published()
   {
    $story = array('author' => $this->session->userdata('username'),
                    'title' => $this->input->post('title'),
                    'synopsis' => $this->input->post('synopsis'));

    $new_storyid = $this->story_model->new_story($story);

    if($new_storyid != NULL)
   {
    $genre = $this->input->post('genre');
    for($temp=0;$temp<count($genre);$temp++)
    {
        $genres[$temp] = array('story_id' => $new_storyid,
                    'story_genre_name' => $genre[$temp]);
     }
    $insert_genre = $this->story_model->new_story_genre($genres);
    $tag = $this->input->post('tags');
    for($temp=0;$temp<count($tag);$temp++)
    {
        $tags[$temp] = array('story_id' => $new_storyid,
                    'story_tag_name' => $tag[$temp]);
    }

    $content_warning = $this->input->post('content_warning');
    for($temp=0;$temp<count($content_warning);$temp++)
    {
        $content_warnings[$temp] = array('story_id' => $new_storyid,
                'story_content_warning_name' => $content_warning[$temp]);
    }





    //$chapter = array('story_id' => $new_storyid,
    //'chapter_number' => 1, 'chapter_title' =>  $this->input->post('chapter_title'),
    //'chapter_content' => $this->input->post('chapter_content'),
    //'chapter_number' => 1, 'date_added' => mdate('%Y-%m-%d %h-%i-%s',time()));    
    //$result = $this->story_model->add_chapter($chapter);
    //if($result){
    //redirect('account/userprofile_published_stories');}
    }
    }
```

This is my model methods for the above controller method:

```
public function new_story($story)
{
    $this->db->select('user_id');
    $query = $this->db->get_where('users',array('username' => $story['author']))->result();
    foreach($query as $row)
    { $userid = $row->user_id; }
    $publish = array('user_id' => $userid,
       'story_title' => $story['title'],
        'synopsis' => $story['synopsis']);
    $this->db->insert('story',$publish);
    return $this->db->insert_id();
    }

    public function new_story_genre($genre)
    {
    foreach($genre as $row)
     {
    $this->db->insert('story_genre', $row);}

    }

    public function add_chapter($chapter){
    $this->db->where('story_id', $chapter['story_id']);
    return $this->db->insert('chapters', $chapter);
    }
```

I haven't added the other 2 functions for my tags and content warning inserts because i am confused right now. It all works fine, my genre is inserted.

My tables looks like this:
[Story tables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MdK9K.png)

In inserting a story in my above method, the first thing i do is insert a new story row in my story table and returns the `new_storyid` variable.

after that with the new `storyid` i add the genre,tags,content warning then the chapters.

My question is, what should i return in my methods for inserting the genre,tags,contentwarning?

I forgot this part because every model method ive written so far always returns a variable i needed in my controller. My first thought was to return a `TRUE/FALSE` variable if insert is successful/fail but barring special circumstances since ive already processed the data its 100% sure to insert successfully. Should i be returning `TRUE/FALSE` and adding an if statement like:

```
if($insert_genre){
//insert tags here
  if($insert_tags){
    //insert content warning here
       if($insert_content_warning){
       //insert chapters here
       //redirect to view here
       }
  }
}
```

Or can i just not return anything? and if so, is this a proper/right way?

EDIT: I forgot to mention i haven't yet added form_validation rules before all the inserts. So my function will be nested in multiple if statements.
I just edited my model method:

```
public function new_story_genre($genre){
$inserted = 0;
foreach($genre as $row){
$this->db->insert('story_genre', $row);
$inserted += $this->db->affected_rows();}
if($inserted == count($genre)){
return TRUE;}else{ return FALSE; }
}
```

Above compares the number of inserted rows with the number of rows passed into the method. Everytime a row is inserted it adds 1 to the inserted variable. So if my controller passes 3 rows into the method, the inserted variable should also be 3 for a successful insert.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are correct in *always* returning something. Errors can and do happen for whatever reason, and its a good idea to account for them even if you already validated your data (you never know). Coding practices suggest that more than a couple of nested ifs is bad practice. A personal preference of mine is to check for failure rather than success all the way down the chain until the last lines of the function (if it got that far than everything is good to go).

A scheme like this I usually use:

```
public function something() {
    if (!$insert_genre) {
        // add flash error message
        // redirect to controller
    }
    if (!$insert_tags) {
        // add flash error message
        // redirect to controller
    }
    if (!$insert_content_warning) {
        // add flash error message
        // redirect to controller
    }
    // yay, something went right!
}
```

In this kindof circumstance it is very procedural. The most important conditions should be first, and if C depends on A, then A should be the first condition.

Unrelated:

It is hard to follow some of your text here, but it also seems like you should look into how you are doing the genres. If the entered genre already exists in the database do you really need to add it? Shouldn't you just use a relationship there storing the id in the main table and joining when displaying?

Comment: I have tags and genre and content warning tables in my database. In my form i use foreach loop to print those. 
 <tr>
 <div class="form-group">
  <td><label for="tag">Tags</label></td>
  <td>
  <?php foreach($tags as $row){ ?>
  <div class="col-lg-2">
  <input type="checkbox" name="tags[]" value="<?=$row->tag_name?>">
  <?=$row->tag_name?>
  </input>
  </div>
  <?php }?>
  </td>
 </div>
So if i get the input post it is already in array form.

Comment: I used it like that to control the genre/tags/content warning. That's why my other table for inserting a story is named story_tags, story_genre, story_content_warning. To differentiate.

Comment: I was making a suggestion on you insert update functions not your display function.

Comment: I also get the checking for failures part. So in my controller i only need to check if the insert is a failure and if so directly redirect it to my view printing the error thus breaking the function and if theres no error then the function will just continue. right?

Comment: I don't update anything for inserting genre/tags/content_warning. 

I insert them into separate tables with their corresponding story_id. Also since the form itself is not an input text and a checkbox there's no worry for any duplicates.

So in my story_genre table. there could be multiple rows of genre 'horror' but different story_id

Comment: Yeah I get that but what I'm saying is instead in your stories table you store the genre Id that way your stories genre table isn't so full of what is essentially duplicate genres. And yeah if the insert fails it will redirect and nothing else will have,essentially the same as an exit.

Comment: What should be the type? Text? and store it as a string like.
1,2,3,4,5 then just explode it all to array form.

explode(',',$genre) ? Btw, ive also thought of this but i also am gonna add a function wherein i can search by genre/tag. The way ive done it now is i can just write 1 query to get all the stories with that tag/genre

Comment: Or is it better to just store their names? Then again, if i were to query it by genre/tag name then id have to get all these data and explode to array then compare. makes the code longer.

Comment: I just reread your scheme. Isnt it still nested if?
If(not true/genre){
redirect}else{ //process
if(not true again/tags){
redirect}else{//process
if(not true again/content warning){
redirect} else {//process}}}

Can you go into detail regarding your scheme. Where do i process my data?

Comment: I was under the impression that $insert_genre was the call to the insert model function (where you process your data). My scheme doesn't contain any elses.